# Segfault after the return 0;

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, itk

I would like to use ITK for a simple color-ratio program, but I get a segfault after the return 0; of the main function.
here is my code.

```
#include "itkImage.h"
#include "itkImageFileReader.h"
#include "itkImageFileWriter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "itkRGBPixel.h"


const unsigned int  Dimension = 2;
typedef itk::RGBPixel< unsigned char >       PixelType;
typedef itk::Image< PixelType, Dimension >   ImageType;
typedef itk::ImageFileReader< ImageType >    ReaderType;
typedef itk::ImageFileWriter< ImageType >   WriterType;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
std::string input=argv[1], output=argv[2];

//allocation of the image data
ReaderType::Pointer reader    = ReaderType::New();
WriterType::Pointer writer = WriterType::New();

reader->SetFileName(input);
writer->SetFileName(output);

reader->Update(); 

//access image
ImageType::Pointer image = reader->GetOutput();
ImageType::Pointer output_img;

 //apparently providing the spacing and origin in ITK is mandatory
ImageType::SpacingType spacing;
spacing[0] = 0.33;
spacing[1] = 0.33;
image->SetSpacing(spacing);

ImageType::PointType origin;
origin[0] = 0.0;
origin[1] = 0.0;
image->SetOrigin(origin);

writer->SetInput( reader->GetOutput() ); 
    writer->Update(); 

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It compiles and links without any error messages but I have a segfault during execution.
By executing the program line by line using gdb, I pinpionted the segfault to the last line of the program: after return 0;

Here is the backtrace

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb79099bc in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb79099bc in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0xb7909a4e in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() ()
from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
 #2  0x08065369 in main (argc=3, argv=0xbffff1b4) at /home/thibault/workspace/OU/MachineLearning/Project1/src/itkTry1.cpp:221
(gdb)
```

and when checking with valgrind:

```
    ==16671== Memcheck, a memory error detector
    ==16671== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
    ==16671== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
    ==16671== Command: ./ColorRatio clouds2.jpeg coucou.jpeg --track-origins=yes
    ==16671== 
    ==16671== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==16671==    at 0x4B28DD8: inflateReset2 (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
    ==16671==    by 0x4B28EC7: inflateInit2_ (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
    ==16671==    by 0x4C87E58: ??? (in /usr/lib/libITKniftiio.so.3.20.1)
    ==16671== 
    ==16671== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    ==16671==    at 0x4B28DD8: inflateReset2 (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
    ==16671==    by 0x4B28EC7: inflateInit2_ (in /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
    ==16671== 
    ==16671== Invalid read of size 4
    ==16671==    at 0x47429BC: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
    ==16671==    by 0x47CE4D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
    ==16671==  Address 0xfffffffc is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
    ==16671== 
    ==16671== 
    ==16671== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
    ==16671==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFFFFFFC
    ==16671==    at 0x47429BC: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
    ==16671==    by 0x47CE4D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
    ==16671==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
    ==16671==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
    ==16671==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
    ==16671==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
    ==16671==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
    ==16671== 
    ==16671== HEAP SUMMARY:
    ==16671==     in use at exit: 2,352,658 bytes in 63,532 blocks
    ==16671==   total heap usage: 74,071 allocs, 10,539 frees, 14,082,941 bytes allocated
    ==16671== 
    ==16671== LEAK SUMMARY:
    ==16671==    definitely lost: 49 bytes in 2 blocks
    ==16671==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==16671==      possibly lost: 1,309,540 bytes in 42,156 blocks
    ==16671==    still reachable: 1,043,069 bytes in 21,374 blocks
    ==16671==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==16671== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
    ==16671== 
    ==16671== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
    ==16671== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
    ==16671== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Even with 36000 useless try/catch statments, I still get that same segmentation fault after the main.

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It seems you are corrupting the stack. Can you please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't really return from `main` with `-1`. Any non-zero number is normally considered an error, and if you want to be sure then return with [`EXIT_FAILURE`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status).

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have edited the code to an SSCCE format. It is short enough, self contained and it compiles. Basically what it does is read an image from a file and directly rewrites it in another file. Nothing else (that I am aware of). The problem remains

Comment: BTW the picture is a png picture.

Comment: ["fatal error: itkImage.h: No such file or directory"](http://ideone.com/1KFYH)  Nope, not an SSCCE.

Comment: I am using the Itk library! Short of providing the entire build with it or copy-pasting the entire content of every single header/source file of the library, there is no possible way to make a sscce!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "itkImage.h"
#include "itkImageFileReader.h"
#include "itkImageFileWriter.h"
#include "itkRGBPixel.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::string input = "/home/doriad/temp/test.png";
  std::string output= "output.png";

  const unsigned int  Dimension = 2;
  typedef itk::RGBPixel< unsigned char >       PixelType;
  typedef itk::Image< PixelType, Dimension >   ImageType;
  typedef itk::ImageFileReader< ImageType >    ReaderType;
  typedef itk::ImageFileWriter< ImageType >   WriterType;

  //allocation of the reader
  ReaderType::Pointer reader    = ReaderType::New();
  reader->SetFileName(input);
  reader->Update();

  //access image
  ImageType::Pointer image = reader->GetOutput();
//  ImageType::Pointer output_img;// This line does nothing

  //apparently providing the spacing and origin in ITK is mandatory
  // The spacing and origin are read from the file.
//  ImageType::SpacingType spacing;
//  spacing[0] = 0.33;
//  spacing[1] = 0.33;
//  image->SetSpacing(spacing);

//  ImageType::PointType origin;
//  origin[0] = 0.0;
//  origin[1] = 0.0;
//  image->SetOrigin(origin);

  WriterType::Pointer writer = WriterType::New();
  writer->SetFileName(output);
  writer->SetInput( reader->GetOutput() );
  writer->Update();

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Of course, you have to change the 'input' string to a file you actually have.

Comment: Alright thank you. I guess the error comes from the setSpacing or setOrigin. Why is it mandatory to use it if one only uses itk for non medical oriented image processing? Anyway thank you for your help. problem solved.

Comment: The reader will produce what you'd expect for spacing (1's) and origin (0's) if your file does not say otherwise (i.e. if you read a non-medical file (like a normal png). You have closed the question properly by accepting the answer.